# Backbone Marionette - images not displaying reliably on iPad - race condition?

Tags: image, ipad, backbone.js, safari, marionette

This is really weird behavior.  Having difficulty even quantifying.  Have had to revise a few times.

Best I can do is the following:

The tech stack for my app is Backbone Marionette, handlebars.js, require.js.

The app contains images mostly of icon size - say 32x32 and under.  Some jpg, some png, some svg.

Some of the images, the same ones each time, don't display.  That's a common issue on which many have posted.  No big news there.

But if I hit the sleep button, leave the iPad sit for a minute or two until the unit really goes into hibernate mode, and then revive it, the images slowly and magically fade in.  They don't abruptly display when the screen lights.  They fade in afterward.

Doesn't work to just hit the sleep button and instantly revive.  Have to wait a minute until it truly hibernates.

After true hibernation, no matter how many times I refresh the page, the images are there.  But, if I go and clear the cache on Safari and load the page, the images are not there again - until I do that hibernate thing.

All of these images do display without fail in a browser on a PC (all flavors).  It's just on the iPad that they don't.

I thought, at first, it was just images I was loading in collection views.  It is not.  I have a third party HTML5 video player in the app.  It has a play button and other controls in svg format.  This also exhibits the behavior above.

Once the iPad has hibernated and been revived, the images fade in.  Only clearing cache makes them disappear again.

There are no 404 errors when the images don't display (checked in dev console on a MAC).  In fact, if I just tap the screen where the video play button is supposed to display, the player begins.  So the button seems to actually be there, just not painted on the screen - until you do that hibernate thing.

Some images in the app always load no matter what.  I'm looking at those images to see if I can note anything special about them or the code which renders them.

I tend to think it's not the images themselves because the very same images in a plain web page always display on the iPad.  Also, that third party video player in a plain web page displays the svg play button and controls without fail on the iPad.

It's just in my app that the behavior occurs.  So it's logical to think my app is where the problem lies.  I just can't seem to find a common thread for the images that always work vs ones that don't.

Not sure what code I can even post here.  I'll look and see what might make sense to post.

Comment: Can you update your question with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a problem loading images dynamically via the framework.  They are there but do not paint.  No idea what the problem actually is.  Literally only happens on Safari mobile browser.  Can't make it happen anywhere else, even old IE.  Know one solution that definitely works though.  Preload all the images by explicitly including them in a div in your markup.  When you load your marionette app, remove the div - $("#preload-images").remove().  Thereafter the images never fail to paint when added dynamically via marionette.

Comment: Further corroboration.  I have another project where I control slide shows on receiver iPads with a controller iPad.  All iPad models same - 2's.  The receiver iPads are a mix of IOS 7 and 8.  Some slide jpg's don't paint on the 7's.  They always paint on the 8's.